# 2 Dimensional Array with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am learning about pointers in c++ and I am not sure what else I am missing in my code. I am simply trying to get the sum of the the elements in a 2 dimensional array.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

//function prototype

int totalRow(int *arr, int row, int col);

int main(){


    int r, c;
    std::cout<<"How many rows in array?: ";
    std::cin>>r;

    std::cout<<"How many columns in array?: ";
    std::cin>>c;

    std::cout<<std::endl;

    int arr[r][c];

    for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
    {

        for(int e=0; e<c; e++)
        {

            std::cout<<"Enter arr[ "<<i+1<<"] [ "<<e+1<<" ]"<<std::endl;
            std::cin>>arr[i][e];
        }

    }

    std::cout<<totalRow(arr,r,c)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int totalRow(int *arr, int row, int col)
{
    int sum=0;

    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {

        for(int e=0; e<col; e++)
        {

            sum+=*arr[i][e]; // I get an error here saying: subscripted value is  

                            // not an array, pointer, or vector

        }

    }

    return sum;
}
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Any self-respecting C++ compiler should've first given you an error for the "totalRow(arr,r,c)" line in `main()`, since a two-dimensional array cannot be converted to an `int *`. `int []` can be converted to an `int *`, but `int [][]` cannot.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[r][c];
```

The type of arr is `int[r][c]`, it can't be converted to `int*`
You can pass the 2D array using template

```
template <size_t R, size_t C>
int totalRow(int(&arr)[R][C]);
```